# load data from file in different package in java

Tags: java

me and my friend 
I have project java and have class like this

```
package me;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class NewClass implements Serializable {
  int x;
  NewClass(int x) {
    this.x = x;
   }
 }
```

and have main class

```
package me;

public class Me{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass ob = new NewClass(4);
    try {
        ResourceManager.save(ob, "temp.data");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication19.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

}
```

and my friend have

```
package myfriend;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class NewClass implements Serializable {

int x;

NewClass(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

}
```

and my freind main class

```
package myfriend;


public class JavaApplication20 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        NewClass ob = (NewClass) ResourceManager.load("temp.data");
        System.out.println(ob.x);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication20.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
ex);
        }

    }   
}
```

and ResourceManager class for clear

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ResourceManager {

public static void save(Serializable data, String fileName) throws Exception 
{
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new 
ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
        oos.writeObject(data);
    }
}

public static Object load(String fileName) throws Exception {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new 
ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
        return ois.readObject();
    }
}
}
```

I send file **temp.data** to my friend and when he want to load object from it

this exception occurs

***java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.NewClass***

What is the solution to this problem؟

**in other word:
This problem encountered me when I tried to transfer files from server to client with serverSocket and Socket**